# Meteor: jQueryValidation remote using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate, meteor

I'm trying to use jQueryValidation: remote for meteor javascript function to validate email on signup form.

Javascript validation:

```
$("#register-form").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            // remote: don't know what to do
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: "Please enter your email",
            remote: "Please enter another one. This email is already exist"
        },
    }
    //...
});
```

Meteor function:

```
Template.tmp_signup.events({
    'change #inpSignupEmail': function () {
        if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
            var data = document.getElementById("inpSignupEmail").value;
            var findOut = UserCustomer.find({Email: data});
            if (findOut.fetch().length > 0) {
                console.log("this email is already exist. too bad");
            }
            else {
                console.log("this is a new email!");
            }
        }
    },  
}
```

So far, my '`change #inpSignupEmail`' function works, but of course, all i get is only a console log: "this email is already exist. too bad".

Is it possible to use my javascript function for jQueryValidation: remote?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with @Sparky 's answer of using `addMethod()` I found this code fragment works beautifully in my case:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myMeteor", function (value, element) {
    if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
        var data = value;  // 'value' argument represents the value of your input
        var findOut = UserCustomer.find({Email: data});
        if (findOut.count() > 0) {
            return false;  // fails - display error    
        }
        else {
            return true;  // passes - no message
        }
    }
});
```

P.S.: Thanks to @Sparky for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `remote` with your JavaScript because `remote` is for remotely checking something on the server and reading the response.

Rather, you're going to have to use [the plugin's `addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to write your own rule incorporating your other JavaScript.

Something like this, although I'm assuming your meteor function already works properly...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myMeteor", function(value, element) {
    Template.tmp_signup.events({
        'change #inpSignupEmail': function () {
            if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
                var data = value;  // 'value' argument represents the value of your input
                var findOut = UserCustomer.find({Email: data});
                if (findOut.fetch().length > 0) {
                    return false;  // fails - display error
                }
                else {
                    return true;  // passes - no message
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}, "this email is already exist. too bad");
```

declared within `.validate()`...

```
$("#register-form").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            myMeteor: true
        }
    }, ......
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea of using the addMethod() method. Apparently I have to modify my meteor function a bit to make it works. I'll post my working solution right away.